# How do we label each value in Y axis using GNUplot

Tags: gnuplot

I have a plotted graph using the below in GNUPlot

[image: GNU Plot Data]

How do I name each section like 10Mb/s, 15Mb/s, 20Mb/s ,etc in Y Axis?

Currently, I have done

```
gnuplot> set xlabel "TIME INSECONDS"
gnuplot> set ylabel "Throughput In Mbps"
gnuplot> set title "ESX Throughput"
gnuplot> plot "esxdata.csv" with linespoints linestyle 1
```

Answer (score 0):

nvm it was

```
set ytics format "%0.0s Mbp/s"
```

From
https://livebook.manning.com/book/gnuplot-in-action-second-edition/chapter-8/146